# How to resolve a load error for gems in ruby on rails, nokogiri/bootsnap specifically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, bootsnap

I couldnt find an answer to this question so...

I am using ruby 2.2.5 with rails 6.1.1 on a mac

I have played around with changing these versions as well but unsuccessfully...

I keep getting this error when I enter 'rails c' to drop into the rails console

`` 1: from /Users/allisonperry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi' /Users/allisonperry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError) ``

I've spent so long trying to figure it out and I am curious if someone can follow this error message better than me and will know what is going on...

thank you very much in advance